# UK Visitor Visa: Is the fact me and my girlfriend are planning to get married in her country good evidence she will leave again

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, standard-visitor-visas, applications, russian-citizens

I am a UK citizen and my long-time girlfriend is a Russian citizen. She has visited the UK once before a year ago on a visitor visa for a month.

In around 6 months we plan to get married in Russia, and then to apply for a family visa to stay in the UK. Until that time, I would like for her to stay with me for a few months on a visitor visa (I can't go to Russia right now due to lockdown rules, and the family visa is too expensive right now -- I'm starting a PhD in October which would give me the funds). Would it be sensible to be upfront on my visa application about my plans, and are these plans sensible?

Thank you

Comment: If your girlfriend does not have any other strong ties to Russia such as a job, dependent family, and you can provide documentation to back up your plan (eg wedding venue booking) then it can do no harm IMHO. Although such plans can be easily changed so are probably not particularly strong compelling evidence of intention to leave.

Comment: As a side note, is she even allowed to travel to GB right at this moment?

Answer (score 0):

If you provide documentation and plans to get married, proof of your relationship and other documents, she can get a marriage visitor visa for 6 months. She can come and visit, stay with you and then you can get married in the UK as well.

The problem with this is that she has to leave the UK after her visit. Then she can apply for a family visa from Russia.  And, not sure about the UK, but I guess with the Covid-19, it would be hard to plan to get married.

She can't

- live in the UK for extended periods through frequent visits
- extend this visa or switch to another visa
- work - except for permitted activities related to your work or
  business overseas, such as attending meetings

And yes, if she has strong ties with Russia, and can provide all the documents like bank statements and all- she can get a standard visitor visa and come as well.